# Как получить индекс элемента массива через event.target?

Tags: javascript

[image]
Нужно достать индекс массива у кликнутого элемента, пробовал IndexOf и findIndex - не сработали! Может возможно раскукожить этот обьект и взять индекс оттуда?(img)

Answer (score 0):

У тебя на скрине виртуальное дерево реакта, а ты хочешь так понимаю получить из реального. Как бэ это разные вещи, по виртуальному дереву строится реальное. Ты можешь вот так сделать

```
<button onClick={(event) => myMethod(event, 3)}
const myMethod = (event, index)
```